# Break AJAX for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, for-loop, error-handling

Newbie here. I have an Ajax function that loops through 3 different requests. However, if the first request fails, I want the other requests to terminate. I tried putting in a 'break' statement but got an 'Illegal break statement' error, I'm guessing since it's not directly inside the for loop, but rather two layers down. I can think of some messy ways to solve this issue, but I'm wondering what a good, simple solution would be...

```
function runQueries(request) {
var reports = ['103, 187, 190'];
for (i=0; i < reports.length; i++) {
    report = reports[i];
    $.ajax({
    url: 'proxy.php',
    data: {requrl: request + '&reportType=' + report},
    dataType: 'xml'
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        if ($(response).find('Locations').children('Location').length < 1) {
            displayError(response, report);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

[.fail()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

instead of `break`  use `i =reports.length+1;`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'proxy.php',
    data: {requrl: request + '&reportType=' + report},
    dataType: 'xml'
    })
    .fail(function() {
         i =reports.length+1;

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work, since I want to terminate the loop even if it's not technically a fail. For example, even if the response gets sent over fine, if it has no 'location' nodes, then I want to terminate the loop

Comment: @Ben321 okay Try replace `break` with `i =reports.length+1`;